# Symmetric Banded-Toeplitz Matrix Norm and Projector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics

Let the following Symmetric Banded-Toeplitz Matrix of size $N$ be defined as
\begin{equation}
\pmb{T}(\pmb{c})
=
\begin{bmatrix}
c_0 & c_1 & c_2 & \cdots  & c_{m-1} & 0 & \cdots  &   0\\
c_1 & c_0 & c_1 & \cdots  & c_{m-2} & c_{m-1} & \cdots  &   0\\
\vdots    &  &     & \ddots & \ddots & & & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & c_{m-1} & c_{m-2} & \cdots & c_1 & c_0 & c_1\\  
0 & \cdots  & 0 & c_{m-1} & \cdots & c_2 & c_1 & c_0\\  
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Can we bound or say anything about the following:

1) $\Vert \pmb{T}(\pmb{c}) \pmb{x} \Vert^2 \leq $ ??

2) If $\pmb{P_A} = \pmb{A}(\pmb{A}^{\text{H}}\pmb{A})^{-1}\pmb{A}^{\text{H}}$, can we say anything about $\pmb{P_{\pmb{T}(\pmb{c})A}}$ ??